# A simple event system | How to?

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js

I want to implement this interface

```
addListener(name, callback);
removeListener(name, [callback]); // callback is optional
trigger(name);
```

All events will be triggered on an internal event bus

```
var bus = {}
```

that is not part of the interface.

This is the simplest interface I could imagine that is actually useful.

However I still don't how to implement these interfaces conceptually.  I've perused the [backbone event system](http://backbonejs.org/#Events), but can't quite understand how they implement this core functionality.

I just want to write a quick 10-100 line event system that is as simple as possible and based upon the more complex Backbone event system.

Comment: The event names should be properties of the "bus" object. The value of each event property should be an array of functions to call when the event is triggered.

Comment: The "addListener" function should add the handler to the handler array on the appropriate property.  The "trigger" function should just call each function in the array, one after another.

Comment: @pure_code: It *is* easy :-)

Comment: looking further, this is what the backbone event system does, it just adds two additional interfaces - space separated events and an object literal notation to connect events to callbacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Backbone.Events module for it.

Stolen shamelessly from [lostechies](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/03/revisiting-the-backbone-event-aggregator-lessons-learned/)

You could use an Application level event aggregator:

```
MyApp = {};
MyApp.vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);

MyApp.vent.on("some:event", function(){
  alert("some event was fired!");
});

MyApp.vent.trigger("some:event");
```

Comment: This is a common idiom, an aggregator or bus have you.  Consequently, I just built a bus in to my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the minimal event bus library [minibus.js](https://github.com/axelpale/minibus). It currently has different API but might be exactly what you are looking for.

```
var bus = Minibus.create();
bus.on(name, callback);  // add listener
bus.emit(name);          // trigger event
bus.off(name);           // remove listener
```